# It is possible to save both Gabriel and Petra?

Tags: minecraft-story-mode

I'm at the part where Jesse and his friends; and Gabriel try to escape from the Witherstorm by going into the obsidian chamber to the Nether. In the part when Gabriel and Petra start to get sucked by the Witherstorm, you get a choice of saving one of them first. I chose Gabriel, then I have to duck when to tentacle hits me and then there is a target in it. But whenever I try to aim at it, it keeps hitting me sending Jesse and Lukas into the Nether. Then the portal gets destroyed. I'm sure it I made an attempt to hit the tentacle, I would be able to save Petra. Am I right or wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to save both. That quicktime event is impossible- [people have used bots and still failed it](https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftStoryMode/comments/3wcsvg/spoiler_can_anyone_answer_those_two_questions/).

The character you save first will escape and the other will be consumed by the Witherstorm.

Comment: Okay, but is it still possible to hit the tentacle, even though I can't save both Petra and Gabriel?

Comment: As I said in my answer, no.

Comment: So if I save Gabriel, Petra will get sucked and vice versa.

Comment: @Jim Yes. Welcome to Telltale Games.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's very much possible if you dodge the tentacle (extremely hard). You will get to save both of them but just some information: if you save Petra she will come back after a while, if you save Gabriel he won't lose his memories but you are separated with Petra until you save her.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this? I'm aware absence of proof is not proof of absence but still...

Answer (score -1):

It isn't possible to save Gabriel at all. No matter who you choose, Gabriel will sacrifice himself, and petra will escape.

Comment: First: There's already an answer. Second: You can save Gabriel, but you can't save both.